# pm2 restarts nodejs process with no indications why

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I installed NodeJS v8.1.2 on an Amazon Linux Distribution on aws.

I have pm2 installed that is in-charge of restarting process in cases it fails.

I catch uncaught exceptions in the process and log them so the process wont restart since I use socket.io and I don't want users to get disconnected on every single exception.

about two month ago after updating nodejs to v7, nodejs would restart randomly with no reason what so ever, so I decided to compile nodejs from sources using nvm, and it resolved the issue.

about a week ago I updated nodejs again to v8.1.2 and today the process restarted again with no reason at all, no exception... nothing on the servers stats where too high.. no reason what so ever.

what do I do?

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated

## updates

I checked `/var/log/messages` and I noticed a segmentation fault error at the time of the restart. do I have to create a core dump to investigate the issue further?

can a segmentation fault of the nodejs process can be caused because of my code ?

what do I do ? :)

Comment: Did you figure out what was causing this? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had this situation because of a memory leak.
Try to monitor your RAM.

Comment: I checked and the problem does not relate to the memory consumption of the process. and I doubt I won't see any indication to memory problem in the logs first.